# ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.JesusM:HoloCircleSeekBar:v2.2.2

Tags: android

I am working on a project where I have used `com.github.JesusM:HoloCircleSeekBar:v2.2.2` library. When I tried to make the build in my system, it worked without any issue but when I tried to run the same project in other system it got the issue that the library can't be resolved. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

you can read the instruction in the Github page of the library

add this line in the build.gradle repositories in project level

```
maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
```

like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}
```

also, you can download the source code and add to your project as a module(the library not updated for 4 years so a lot of changes happens) and change dependencies and codes to work properly